# What is the intuition of "averaging is a low pass filter"?

Tags: filters, lowpass-filter, averaging

As I know, the shape of a low pass filter in time and frequency are as follow:

[image]

- But how averaging work like a normal function in time domain?
- Is there any intuition in it?

Comment: Can you explain using DFT as to why an averaging filter is low pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First intuition: If you symmetrize the top plot across the $y$-axis, you will see a bell-shaped function. For real filters, one usually only plots the right-most part, since the Fourier magnitude  is symmetric. The most notable example of a bell-shaped function is the Gaussian, and the Fourier transform of a Gaussian is a Gaussian too. So half a Gaussian on the left of the Fourier domain is like full Gaussian in time.

Second intuition: perform a moving average of two-sample width on a signal. Do that again, and again, again ([like in a forest](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dzFmlRCyVUs)). Those combined averages tend to a Gaussian.

Finally, a caveat: the curvature of your top plot is only one possibility for a low-pass filter. Moving average filters (with $M$ length) are brick-like, and their Fourier domain counterparts do not look like Gaussians.

[image: Moving average filters]

Answer (score 9):

Consider a sequence of numbers

```
x = [1, 100, 1, 100, 1, 100]
```

If we send this sequence through an averaging transformation

```
y(i) = 0.6*x(i) + 0.4*x(i-1)
```

we get

```
y = [1, 60.4, 40.6, 60.4, 40.6, 60.4]
```

Original signal x had a lot of sudden changes `1 -> 100, 100 -> 1` where as signal y has smaller changes `60 -> 40, 40 -> 60`

When we say that a signal has high frequency components we mean that the values change rapidly with time. So x had rapid changes in amplitude, while y does not have that much of rapid changes in values. This is the intuition behind why averaging is equivalent to low-pass filtering (disallowing high frequencies).

--

Another way to look at it

```
x = [1, 100, 1, 100, 1, 100]
```

could be written as sum of two sequences, x1 and x2

Low(zero?) frequency component

```
x1 = [50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50]
```

High frequency component

```
x2 = [-49, 50, -49, 50, -49, 50]
```

After averaging transformation, we get

```
y = [1, 60.4, 40.6, 60.4, 40.6, 60.4]
```

Which has low frequency component of

```
y1 = [50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50]
```

and high frequency component

```
y2 = [-49, 10.4, -9.4, 10.4, -9.4, 10.4]
```

As you can see that y2 has much smaller absolute amplitudes than x2, meaning that **we have diminished the high frequency components in x by doing averaging.**

Answer (score 3):

Well, as far as intuitive thinking goes, I was thinking something along these terms: if you have two numbers, $a\neq b$, and you do an average between them, the average will *always* come *between* those numbers, which means that its value will always be *lower* than the highest (but also higher than the lowest). So the average will never converge upwards of the highest numbers, even if you have $999$ terms of $1e6$ and $1$ term of $1e-6$. The average will be less than the highest numbers, so the high numbers will get diminished, while the lower numbers increased. Just another way of looking at things.